# How to create an input formfield with button that uploads a file using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am new to programming and learning on the go. what i am trying to do currently is to create a form field like below that uploads a file on clicking a button.

[image]

and once file uploaded and before submitting the file to api should see the file name in form field like below

[image]

i have tried like below but that shows only browse file button but doesnt sow the input field with Add file placeholder.

```
<input
    type="file"
    id={`${fieldRoot}.file`}
    ref={fileInput}
    style={{ display: 'none' }}
    accept=".pem"
    onChange={() => {
        /*do something*/
            console.log('hello')
     }}
 />
 <Button
     minWidth="126px"
     //onClick={handleUploadClick}
 >
     Browse file
 </Button>
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You don't need a `<button>` element, as the `<input type="file"/>` **is** the browse-button, while you'll need a separate element (a `<label>` or `<span>` will do) to show the filename of the selected file(s).

Comment: thanks i have added an image for how input with button should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `<input type="file"/>` also is a input. So you can use `<label>` tag and style it look like a button. In this case, I use image instead.
- I'm using `hidden` attribute to make the actual `<input />` invisible.

```js
          <input
            type="file"
            id="avatar"
            onChange={fileSelectedHandler}
            hidden
          />
          <label className={profileStyle.uploadLabel} htmlFor="avatar">
            <Image
              width="25px"
              height="25px"
              src="/icons/upload-image-icon.jpeg"
              alt="upload-avatar"
            />
          </label>
```

Here is what you want:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Upload = () => {
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={filename}
        type="text"
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 28,
          padding: 0,
          border: "1px solid #767676"
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        id="upload"
        hidden
        onChange={(e) => {
          // You have your file detail in e.tartget.files
          console.log(e.target.files[0]);
          setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
        }}
      />
      <label
        htmlFor="upload"
        style={{
          width: 90,
          background: "#767676",
          color: "#fff",
          padding: 5
        }}
      >
        Browse
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

Check this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-voice-ze5fme?file=/Components/Upload.js:0-818)

Comment: i have added pics for how the input with button should look like. thanks.

Comment: @natalia I added a Codesandbox. Check it.